# Need to Create Screen Saver from Scratch

Tags: visual-studio-2010, flash, 64-bit, screensaver

I've hit a bit of a stump on the road to my goal of creating a screen saver. Before I began this project I did research and everyone urged me to create the screen saver using flash.. in which I did. Now I face the issue of converting it to an SCR (screen saver format for windows) . Now I've done my research and downloaded Instantstorm only to be disappointed by it's lack of 64-bit support and/or Multi-monitor support (Scaled mirroring across screens if resolution of main screen is different from other screens).

Can anyone tell me what is the proper way of creating an animated screen saver from scratch (or from the flash file I created preferably)  which is fully compatible with 64-bit and has the ability to display the screen saver on multiple monitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a flash app you may be able to run it through a browser/as a web page. See this post for additional info:

[webpage as a screensaver windows 7 and XP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548174/webpage-as-a-screensaver-windows-7-and-xp)

Comment: Using a webpage as a screensaver is not an option

Comment: I will mark it as the answer as it does answer my question as an alternative to creating a screen saver from scratch. My solution was taken care of by Instantstorm's support team

Answer (score 0):

When I create screensavers, I do it through java, and then use launch4j to convert it to a .exe file. I then rename that .exe file .scr.
If you have issues renaming the file, go to control panel>folder options and uncheck "hide extensions for known file types". You can then rename the file.

P.S. If you are able to create a .exe file with flash, then you can just rename it from .exe to .scr as the extenstion.